# How to estimate gas cost (not gas price) per transaction?

Tags: gas, bsc, gas-estimate, pancakeswap, bscscan

Sorry for the newbie question.

So i had 2 different transactions with the same gas price and same function called

But it used different amount of gas unit (not gas price)

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x67f844f7bbb5b268b8457ee5de16d52f96f67c94368c62f31cbfa19c3a76cc9e

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd899172f4c00b536ba17829a5cf435a5188cea9c44a1fe43adb36b6afe8d1dd3

Is there any factor which affect gas cost, or any method or equation to estimate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gas cost depends on what the executed transaction/function does. If for example Tipsy Santa charges fees on transfer of token, it will be more expensive (gas-wise) to swap it, as the transaction will do additional calculations.

Comment: So does it mean calling the same function for buying on the same token, will cost a same and fixed gas cost between the two transactions?

Comment: Not always, it depends what the function does. For example somebody might code a function that uses 1000 gas when you first use it, but will cost 20000 gas when you call it for the second time.